# Result of the __init__(self) related method is not showing up

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@company.com'

    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

    def pay_raise(self):

        self.pay = int(self.pay * 1.04)


emp_1 = Employee("Mark", "Johnson", 50000)

emp_1.pay_raise()
```

When I write that emp_1.pay_raise() phrase or emp_1.fullname() i dont get any results or any errors either after pressing "run" or "debug" in pycharm. Can you notice any mistakes in my code? I will very appereciate.

Comment: `pay_raise` doesn't return a value; it only changes an attribute. You never *call* `fullname`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `__init__`.

Comment: I would expect this program to run without error and with no output. Are you getting some other result?

Comment: I don't get any result indeed. Program runs without any error as well.

Comment: Hi empique, What is your code to display/ return result ?

Comment: you don't print any result at all.

Comment: Many thanks to you guys. Now I understand everything. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing out any of the "results" from executing the methods. Try this:

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@company.com'

    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

    def pay_raise(self):

        self.pay = int(self.pay * 1.04)


emp_1 = Employee("Mark", "Johnson", 50000)

print(emp_1.fullname())

emp_1.pay_raise()
print(emp_1.pay)
```